# Finding preferred pair of $m$-sequence for Gold code

Tags: digital-communications, coding

I would like to find a preferred pair of $m$-sequence of degree 34 (not a multiple of 4) for Gold code. However, I am lost when I am checking William Wesley Peterson's table in his Error-correcting Codes, Appendix C

[image]

I tried first fix the first entry for my first $m$-sequence. To find the other sequence, since $n = 34$, it is even, then
$$2^{\left(\frac{34+2}{2}\right)}+1 = 2^{18} + 1$$
or
$$2^{\left(\frac{34-2}{2}\right)}+1 = 2^{16} + 1$$

But either number is not mapped to any entry in the table that I cannot proceed to find the other $m$-sequence. I assume I should find the other $m$-sequence which has the equivalent root of
$$r^{\left(2^{\left(\frac{34+2}{2}\right)}+1\right)}$$
or
$$r^{\left(2^{\left(\frac{34-2}{2}\right)}+1\right)}$$

To elaborate, the following is what I consider as an easy case of prefered pair of Gold Sequence using [Peterson's table](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Elomonaco/f97/442/Peterson_Table.html) and Gold's theorem, presented in [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.1334&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I have no access to Dixon's book therefore I don't know what the correct procedure is.

[image]

The author applying the equation in [the conjugate form](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/7894-1.php%20Dilip%20Sarwate) of Gold's theorem in [Gold's paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1054048)

Comment: What do you mean with "this number is way too large"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think what the OP means is that he needs an entry of the form `65537 20135723`$\cdots$ but the table only goes up to `21` and then $3$ selected entries none if which  begins `65537`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printed tables of irreducible polynomials of large degrees are usually incomplete because there are so many of them!  What one *can* do is use various tricks of the trade to figure out a set of $68 = 2\times 34$ consecutive bits of one *m*-sequence from the other *m*-sequence (with known generator polynomial as taken from the Peterson and Weldon table) and then run the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm on these consecutive bits to get the shortest shift register that generates the desired *m*-sequence.

If ${\bf s} = s_0, s_1, s_2, \ldots $ is one of the *m*-sequences, then the other *m*-sequence ${\bf t} = t_0, t_1, t_2, \ldots $ is related to ${\bf s}$ via
$t_i = s_{qi}$ where $q = 2^{16}+1 = 65,537$. See the paper "Cross-correlation properties of pseudorandom and related sequences," Proc. IEEE, vol.68, pp.593-619, May 1980 (unfortunately behind IEEE's paywall, but copies can be found in the Internet) if you are unfamiliar with this idea. So, we crank up the LFSR that generates ${\bf s}$ and run it to produce the sequence ${\bf s}$, recording $$t_0 = s_0, ~~t_1 = s_{65537},~~ t_2 = s_{131074},~~ \cdots, t_{67} = s_{4390979}.$$  Once upon a time, cranking out 4 million+ bits would have taken some effort, but these days, it's no big deal.

What next? Well, the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm can be viewed as a shift-register synthesis algorithm: it finds the shortest LFSR that can generate any given sequence. Thus, applying the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm to the first $68$ bits of $\bf t$ which we have just found gives us the LFSR that generates the *m*-sequence $\bf t$, and away we go!!

Comment: That solves all my confusion...Thank you very much!

Comment: @EagleShou if it solves the confusion, then you might want to accept this (the checkmark next to the up/downvote triangles), so the question gets marked as answered :)